# Open another app from My app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking

I am having two apps. 
I want to open a SecondApp from my FirstApp Button Click.
Second App is having that custom Schema which is required for deep linking.
Now I want to know what code I need to do on my FirstApp button click to open SecondApp?

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: read deep linking first

Comment: @matloobHasnain what if the deep link is not available for app?

Comment: @Sagar then no way to open without deep linking

Answer (score 9):

As much I can tell you in brief.
You need to add custom Url schema for in your application.

For example you need to launch App2 from App1.

This is the code that you need to add in App2 info.plist or you can add "URL Types" in your info section of target.

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.company.App1</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>CompanyApp2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And this is the code that you need to add in you App1 info.plist file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>CompanyApp2</string>
</array>
```

Then you will launch App2 from App1 like as:

```
        let app2Url: URL = URL(string: "CompanyApp2://")!

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(app2Url) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(app2Url)
        }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Works perfectly. Do you know how do direct to a certain view controller within the app with a username/id? e.g. "instagram://user?username=johndoe" opens instagram to the profile page with username of johndoe

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
   let appURL: URL = URL(string: "CustomUrlScheme://")!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL)
    }
```

Answer (score -6):

```
In android, we can perform in the below ways
//Dial a phone
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0377778888"));
startActivity(callIntent);

//View a map
// Map point based on address
Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+California");
// Or map point based on latitude/longitude
// Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:37.422219,-122.08364?z=14"); // z param is zoom level
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
startActivity(mapIntent);
//View a webpage
Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.android.com");
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
startActivity(webIntent);
```